# Mensagem de erro no GlassFish

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Estou usando o **GlassFish 3.1.2.2** junto com o **NetBeans 7.4** e não sei de onde fica dando essa informação toda hora quando eu inicio o servidor:

> INFO: O usuário [admin] do host 127.0.0.1 não possui acesso de
>   administração ou o nome de usuário e a senha fornecidos são incorretos

Comment: Paulo, inclua mais informações sobre o SO que esta usando, o usuário em que está iniciando o glassfish, é "root"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abra as propriedades do servidor em questão e informe a senha correta do administrador na aba de *Conexão*. É provável que a senha informada esteja errada. Por default a senha do usuário **admin** é **adminadmin**.

Para testar se a senha está correta ou não, abra o console de administração do glassfish (localhost:4848) e tente logar com seu usuário **admin**.

Comment: Ola Edgar meu usuario é admin e esta sem senha, eu acesso localhost:4848 tranquilo o problema é que fica essa mensagem no cocnsole de segundo a segundo

Comment: @paulohddias e como está a configuração que eu falei pra você mudar? Está sem senha também?

Comment: Bom dia Edgar esta sim usuario Admin e sem senha pois no incio do servidor ele pede usuario e senha e se eu colocar outra coisa nao loga